# How can I estimate time complexity from a table of values?

Tags: java, time, complexity-theory

I know that my naive matrix multiplication algorithm has a time complexity of O(N^3)...
But how can I prove that through my table of values? Size is the row or column length of the matrix. So square that for the full matrix size.

- Size = 100 Mat. Mult. Elapsed Time: 0.0199 seconds.

  Size = 200 Mat. Mult. Elapsed Time: 0.0443 seconds.

  Size = 300 Mat. Mult. Elapsed Time: 0.0984 seconds.

  Size = 400 Mat. Mult. Elapsed Time: 0.2704 seconds.

  Size = 800 Mat. Mult. Elapsed Time: 6.393 seconds.

This is like looking at a table of values and estimating the graph of the function... There has to be some relationship between these numbers, and N^3. How do I make sense of it though?

I have provided my algorithm below. I already know it is O(N^3) by counting the loops. How can I relate that to my table of values above though?

```
 /**
* This function multiplies two matrices and returns the product matrix.
* 
* @param mat1
*           The first multiplier matrix.
* @param mat2
*           The second multiplicand matrix.
* @return The product matrix.
*/
private static double[][] MatMult(double[][] mat1, double[][] mat2) {
  int m1RowLimit = mat1.length, m2ColumnLimit = mat2[0].length, innerLimit = mat1[0].length;
  if ((mat1[0].length != mat2.length))
     return null;
  int m1Row = 0, m1Column = 0, m2Row = 0, m2Column = 0;
  double[][] mat3 = new double[m1RowLimit][m2ColumnLimit];
  while (m1Row < m1RowLimit) {
     m2Column = 0;
     while (m2Column < m2ColumnLimit) {
        double value = 0;
        m1Column = 0;
        m2Row = 0;
        while (m1Column < innerLimit) {
           value += mat1[m1Row][m1Column] * mat2[m2Row][m2Column];
           m1Column++;
           m2Row++;
        }
        mat3[m1Row][m2Column] = value;
        m2Column++;
     }
     m1Row++;
  }
  return mat3;
}
```

Comment: Observing Time complexity, in the mathematical sense, often involves looking at the algorithm and imagining how it functions for very large inputs. If you can post the algorithm I'm sure we can help you. Your data is based on many, many variables. Things like RAM space, processor speed, physical resistance on the cables. These will all effect the output of your program. Hence, using large values. It masks out these effects. You prove your complexity using either mathematical induction or backward substitution.

Comment: So, you can't look at the table of values I provided above and make out a relation through induction? I'll post the algorithm, if it helps. I already know it is O(N^3) though.

Comment: Yeah but you want to prove it is O(N^3). What you do is you pick out a metric (some measurement) and you use that. You're not actually using units of time. They fluctuate far to much to obtain a pattern from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The methodology

---

Okay. So you want to prove your algorithm's time complexity is `O(n^3)`. I understand why you would look at the time it takes for a program to run a calculation, but this data is not reliable. What we do, is we apply a weird form of [limits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_%28mathematics%29) to abstract away from the other aspects of an algorithm, and leave us with our `metric`.

#### The Metric

---

A `metric` is what we are going to use to measure your algorithm. It is the operation that occurs the most, or carries the most processing weight. In this case, it is this line:

```
value += mat1[m1Row][m1Column] * mat2[m2Row][m2Column];
```

#### Deriving the Recurrence Relation

---

The next step, as I understand it, is to derive a recurrence relation from your algorithm. That is, a description of how your algorithm functions based on it's functionality in the past. Let's look at how your program runs.

As you explained, you have looked at your three while loops, and determined the program is of order `O(n^3)`. Unfortunately, this is not mathematical. This is just something that seems to happen a lot. First, let's look at some numerical examples.

When `m1RowLimit = 4, m2ColumnLimit = 4, innerLimit = 4`, our metric is ran `4 * 4 * 4 = 4^3` times.

When `m1RowLimit = 5, m2ColumnLimit = 5, innerLimit = 5`, our metric is ran `5 * 5 * 5 = 5^3` times.

So how do we express this in a recurrence relation? Well, using some basic maths we get:

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + 3(n-1)^2 + 3(n-1) + 1 for all n >= 1
T(1) = 1
```

#### Solving the Recurrence Relation using Forward Substitution and Mathematical Induction

---

Now, is where we use some [forward substitution](http://math.fullerton.edu/mathews/n2003/BackSubstitutionMod.html). What we first do, is get a feel for the relation (this also tests that it's accurate).

```
T(2) = T(1) + 3(1^2) + 3(1) + 1 = 1 + 3 + 3 + 1 = 8.
T(3) = T(2) + 3(2^2) + 3(2) + 1 = 8 + 12 + 6 + 1 = 27
T(4) = T(3) + 3(3^2) + 3(3) + 1 = 27 + 27 + 9 + 1 = 64
```

NOW, we assert the hypothesis that T(n) = n^3. Let's test it for the base case:

```
T(1) = 1^3 = 1. // Correct!
```

Now we test it, using mathematical induction, for the next step. The algorithm increases by 1 each time, so the next step is: `T(n+1)`. So what do we need to prove? Well we need to prove that by increasing `n` by 1 on one side, the equal effect happens to `n` on the other. If it is true for all `n + 1`, then it is true for `n + 1 + 1` and so on. This means, we're aiming to prove that:

```
T(n + 1) = (n + 1)^3

T(n + 1) = T(n - 1 + 1) + 3(n + 1 - 1)^2 + 3(n + 1 - 1) + 1
         = T(n) + 3(n)^2 + 3(n) + 1
Assume T(n) = n^3
T(n + 1) = n^3 + 3(n)^2 + 3(n) + 1
T(n + 1) = (n+1)^3 // Factorize the function.
```

So at this point, you've proven your algorithm has a run time complexity of `O(n^3)`.

Comment: Wow. VERY informative! Can we use this to calculate theta(N) and omega(N) as well?

Comment: That.. I must admit I'm not sure. Usually I just calculate big(O) and be done with it.

Answer (score 2):

The first response covers how to prove the time complexity of your algorithm quite well.

However, you seem to be asking how to relate the experimental results of your benchmarks with time complexity, *not* how to prove time complexity.

So, how do we interpret the experimental data? Well, you could start by simply plotting the data (runtime on the y-axis, size on the x-axis).  With enough data points, this could give you some hints about the behavior of your algorithm.

Since you already know the expected time complexity of your algorithm, you could then draw a "curve of best fit" (i.e. a line of the shape n^3 that best fits your data).  If your data matches the line fairly well, then you were likely correct.  If not, it's possible you made some mistake, or that your experimental results are not matching due to factors you are not accounting for.

To determine the equation for the best fitting n^3 line, you could simply take the calculated time complexity, express it as an equation, and guess values for the unknowns until you find an equation that fits.  So for n^3, you'd have:

```
t = a*n^3 + b*n^2 + c*n + d
```

Find the values of a, b, c, and d that form an equation that best fits your data. If that fit still isn't good enough, then you have a problem.

For more rigorous techniques, you'd have to ask someone more well versed in statistics. I believe the value you'd want to calculate is the [coefficient of determination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination) (a.k.a. R^2, basically tells you the variance between the expected and actual results). However, on it's own this value doesn't prove a whole lot.  This problem of validating hypothesized relationships between variables is known as [Regression Model Validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_model_validation); the wikipedia article provides a bit more information on how to go further with this if R^2 isn't enough for your purposes.

Comment: Using calculus is an approximation of values. OP wanted a proof, hence why I used recurrence relations and mathematical induction. *"But how can I prove that through my table of values?"*.

Answer (score 2):

Empirically, you can plot your data with an adjacent third-degree polynomial trend-line for reference.

[image: excel chart]

CSV data:

```
100, 0.0199
200, 0.0443
300, 0.0984
400, 0.2704
800, 6.393
```

Comment: Somewhat more simple than my answer! With this graph, can you show that between a range of values for `x`, it tends to behave like a cubic function?

Comment: Subjectively, yes, in the sense that you can adjust the order of the trend-line to see the how the "fit" changes. I meant to complement your & Gudahtt's more dispositive analyses, up-voted at the time I created this answer.

Comment: I see. So if you were putting a paper together about a certain algorithm, you could start with your answer, then Gudahtt's, and finally mine, to make a strong case for the complexity of your algorithm?

Comment: Yes, the spreadsheet's trend-line feature finds Gudahtt's [coefficients](http://arachnoid.com/sage/polynomial.html). One can also do the converse: verify empirically that a particular implementation of an algorithm meets a known complexity requirement. Either [tag:jscience] or [tag:apache-commons-math] work well with [tag:jfreechart] in this context.